# ATtiny10 sleep mode

Tags: pwm, c, programming, attiny, sleep

I have a very basic ongoing project that involves 8 LEDs, push-button tack switch with 10 kΩ pull up resistor, and an ATtiny10 microcontroller. The entire system is powered by a coin cell battery with a capacity of approximately 270 mAh.

The main objective of this project is to maximize the battery life before it runs out. The tack switch serves as an on/off switch. Although I am not proficient in programming, I have managed to develop a working code with the assistance of ChatGPT, as well as extensive googling and reading.

The current code successfully toggles the LEDs on and off. However, when I attempt to incorporate PWM or sleep functions, the code doesn't seem to work.

Below is the working code. Could you please suggest any additions or modifications that could help prolong the battery life?  Specifically, I'm interested in incorporating sleep mode or LED PWM.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

```c
#include <xc.h>
#define F_CPU 8000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define LED_PIN PB0 // Define the pin connected to the LED
#define BUTTON_PIN PB1 // Define the pin connected to the button

int main(void)
{
    DDRB |= (1 << LED_PIN); // Set the LED pin as an output
    PORTB |= (1 << BUTTON_PIN); // Enable the pull-up resistor on the button pin

    uint8_t button_state = 0; // 0 = button released, 1 = button pressed
    uint8_t led_state = 0; // 0 = LED off, 1 = LED on

    while (1) {
        // Read the button state
        uint8_t new_button_state = !(PINB & (1 << BUTTON_PIN));
        if (new_button_state && !button_state) {
            // Button has just been pressed
            led_state = !led_state; // Toggle the LED state
        }
        button_state = new_button_state;

        // Set the LED state
        if (led_state) {
            PORTB |= (1 << LED_PIN); // Turn the LED on
            } else {
            PORTB &= ~(1 << LED_PIN); // Turn the LED off
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried so far in terms of sleep?

Comment: Which of the 4 sleep modes did you try to invoke and how?

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the PWM, that's not about saving power, that's about dimming LEDs. Surely making them less bright also saves power but that's a different question.

To save power with sleep mode your plan should be the following:

1 - Investigate your options in terms of sleep modes. It's not that simple that "sleep mode, no sleep mode bye!". There are different sleep modes, and one main difference is what events can wake up your controller. The most efficient in your case is the *power down*. An external interrupt or pin change interrupt can wake up the thing. That's good.

2 - Investigate how these interrupts work. (Oh, make yourself familiar with the RTFM expression, you will hear it a lot). I would recommend the pin change interrupt. It fires an interrupt (waking up the controller) when the logic level of a pin (hopefully set to input, maybe with a pullup) changes. Of course each click of a button is two changes: one for press and one for release, so you would need to think about how you want to use this.

3 - Work out how your program will work. Its function is repeated all the time: sleep, wake up if button is pressed, handle the LED and so on. So an endless loop is super for this. Inside you need to implement these basic steps:

```
while(1) {
    goSleep(); // The processor will 'hang' here until something wakes it up
    handleLED(); // Do whatever you want, toggle light etc
}
```

That's the basic idea. In power down mode it draws next to nothing from the battery. The pullup resistor might use up more than the cnotroller! :)